# Package explanation

Tags: package-management

I was having issues with my graphics card working on Ubuntu and I had to enter the commands below as part of the process to get it working. I don't know what they are or what they do, so I'd like someone to explain it to me.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install nvidia-curent-updates
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install linux-source` installs linux source. It could not help to solve any problems with anything. This package is needed to build custom kernels.

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` this package is installed in all Ubuntu releases except 12.10, where it was not present due to a bug. This package installs linux headers. They are needed to build kernel modules, like nvidia driver.

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates` installed nvidia driver.

It looks like you could run only last command, if you are not on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I might format and test it just to see if that's the case. I'm interested to know more about the last command then. What is the purpose of it? I seem to have to manually download the latest driver from the nvidia website after I run that command. So I don't know what driver it's doing/using.

Comment: You do not have to download anything. The command will do it for you. Downloading drivers form nvidia site is bad practice that will lead to boot failure after kernel upgrade.

Comment: Oh right. Well I just tested this. I didn't have to run the first 2 commands, like you said. I did run the 3rd command, but after I installed the driver from their website. I will test again and not install the driver from their website.  I have just a quick question for you. On the driver from their website, it asks "would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS?" this will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later." What does this mean, and what is DKMS? It seems to contractict what you're saying, but I don't understand it v.good

Comment: Just tested another format/install again. Turns out if I only run the install nvidia-current updates and don't install the latest driver from the manufacturers website, my PC doesn't boot. Seems I do actually need the manufacturers driver.

Comment: The you do not need any commands at all. It means that driver form Ubuntu repository does not work for your card. But any way you can install a drivers as a package from ppa.  And there is an option if DKMS in .run driver, but it does not work correctly.

Comment: OK please could you explain more about the ppa package? I don't know what it is or why I need it? I'm still fairly new to Linux.

Comment: You can search on "How to install Nvidia drivers" or ask another question. There are a lot of answers on that topic.

Comment: A lot of answers didn't work for me, nor were they clearly explained. I guess I'll just resort to Google again to find my answers.

Answer (score 1):

- `linux-source`

  From `apt-cache show linux-source`

  *Linux kernel source with Ubuntu patches*

  This package will always depend on the latest Linux kernel source code
  available. The Ubuntu patches have been applied.
- `linux-headers-generic`

  From `apt-cache show linux-headers-generic`

  *Generic Linux kernel headers*

  This package will always depend on the latest generic kernel headers
  available.
- `nvidia-current-updates`

  From `apt-cache show nvidia-current-updates`

  *Transitional package for nvidia-current-updates*

  This is a transitional package for nvidia-current-updates, and can be
  safely removed after the installation is complete.